# Installing brew on linux without sudo and older version git and curl

Tags: linux, homebrew

I don't have the sudo permission, I have installed brew.
I have two different git /usr/bin/git (1.8.3.1) and /grid/common/bin/git(2.30.0)
I want to use newer one. How can I make it.

Another is the same issue for curl

In csh shell:

```
>which git
/grid/common/bin/git

>brew --env
Error: Please update your system curl.
Minimum required version: 7.41.0
Your curl version: 7.29.0
Your curl executable:
Error: Please update your system Git.
Minimum required version: 2.7.0
Your Git version: 1.8.3.1
Your Git executable: /usr/bin/git
HOMEBREW_CC: gcc
HOMEBREW_CXX: g++
MAKEFLAGS: -j1
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/jintaol/.linuxbrew
HOMEBREW_GIT: git
PATH: /home/jintaol/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

>which curl
/home/jintaol/app/curl
>curl --version
curl 7.79.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-musl) libcurl/7.79.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1l zlib/1.2.11 libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.42.0
```

Comment: The idea is I can use brew install git/curl to replace the older ones

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a symlink or an alias to link to the desired version of `curl` and added into your shell profile (like `~/.bash_profile`).

Here is what I would do:

- `echo "alias git=/grid/common/bin/git" >> ~/.bash_profile`
- `echo "alias curl=/home/jintaol/app/curl" >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already solved the issue by setup envs HOMEBREW_DEVELOPER HOMEBREW_CURL_PATH, and HOMEBREW_GIT_PATH